# Migrate old records to new database

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration, data-migration

I am new in Laravel. I have setup Laravel and using Laravel Auth.

I am building my old project in Laravel but I am not sure how can I merge my old users to this newly build structure. Does anyone have how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks a lot of information.

With that amount of information I can only suggest you to take a look at the users migration generated by Laravel (or the users table), see the fields and try to create a custom-made script to transform/adapt/import your old users into the new structure Laravel uses